# ScrollView with nested RecyclerViews and bidirectional scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, nested-lists, gridlayoutmanager

I would like to achieve the result shown in the gif below

[image]

Two list views which scroll vertically together and one of them can also scroll horizontally to show more contents.

I saw it in a card from Google Discover and I would like to apply it in one of my projects.
I could try to implement it by myself but since it is used by Google maybe it is already available, for instance as a material design component or so.

I couldn't find anything similar so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in the end using this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:overScrollMode="never">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="2">

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/left_recycler_view"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
           android:layout_weight="1" />

       <HorizontalScrollView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1">

           <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
               android:id="@+id/right_recycler_view"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </HorizontalScrollView>

   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Both the recycler view have a simple `LinearLayoutManager`

> android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" is available only since API 21 so in other cases it needs to be set by code.